# Different text-colors in one div need to change to one color when hovering over div

Tags: css, html

I want to display a line of text with two different colors (black and red). 
When the user hovers over the div where the text is in, the div's background-color changes and ALL the text in the div has to become white.

Using the 'span' element would be a good solution to show different colors on one line.
However, the text in the 'span' element remains red while the other text does change to white when I hover over the div.

So how do I make sure all the text changes to white?
All help is appreciated.

Here is my CSS:

```
.linkBackground
{        
    background-color: White;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a22a29;        
    color: Black;
}

.linkBackground span
{
    color: #a22a29;
}

.linkBackground:hover
{
    background-color: #a22a29;
    border-bottom: 1px solid White;
    color: White;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="linkBackground">
    This is <span>an example</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.linkBackground:hover,
.linkBackground:hover span {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Nope, this won't work; if your mouse is on a non-`span` part of the link, the `span` won't be white.

Comment: I'm currently on my phone, so I'm unable to test; but I can't see why it wouldn't work. =/ if you've tested, and it really doesn't, then I'll delete it obviously. Let me know..?

Answer (score 0):

suggest solution using jQuery
          $('.linkBackground').hover(function() {
                $(this).find('span').css('color', 'hexcode');
          })

Comment: Not only does this solution not work, it's completely pointless and a bad idea to use jQuery for something where it is not needed at all. jQuery is overhyped and overused.

Comment: @Delan Azabani don't blame jQuery....its just too addictive and fun....blame bad coders like me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.linkBackground:hover {
    background-color: #a22a29;
    border-bottom: 1px solid White;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately the !important doesn't work, I already tried that.